# What is following C# code equvalent to C++ CLI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

In C#

```
public class cls {
    public static void met() {
    }
}
```

I want it in C++ CLI.
The method `met` should not be visible to variables which are decelerated as `cls`.

I should be able to :

```
cls::met();
```

I shouldn't be able to :

```
cls z;
z.met();
```

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is `static`. Same as in C#. Post your best try and any errors that came up.

Comment: @nvoigt I have used static already, but `met` is visible to `cls` varialbes

Comment: The problem with `static` in C++ is that you can call static methods on objects, although you will get a warning. So `z.met()` should compile.

Comment: @ArneMertz All I want is prevent z.met() compilation. I don't even get a simple warning !

Comment: @Mahdi, static members not begin callable from instances is a implementation detail of C#, not other languages. C++/CLI retains the ability to call static members from instances, as C++ does.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi So there isn't a way to achieve what I want. right ?

Comment: @Mahdi, right. The language does not support it in the first place.

Comment: What about making it a free function? Just move it outside the class - that's not possible in C#, but it is in C++

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks, maybe your comment is suitable answer to be marked if you post ?

Comment: @ArneMertz I don't get how ?

Comment: @Mahdi see the answer posted by DeadMG

Comment: @ArneMertz Commented on his answer

Comment: @Mahdi And why is it important to forbid z.met()? A static method can't access cls members from it's body and that is imho the only important part for declaring it static (all objects/instances share the same). It is not important how to call it, this is just the syntactic sugar of the language (c#, c++/cli, ...) and you don't know how the compiler optimizes the code. Probably there is no difference between z.met() and cls::met() in the binary result.

Comment: @Beachwalker if there is only one static method then you are right, what if there are over 100 static methods ? those just keep spamming my auto-complete list-box in Visual Studio

Comment: @Beachwalker Actually I have a class of `Vehicle` which I wanted to define Vehicle Models in it as static, There are 212 models which are just useless to be listed...

Comment: @Mahdi How to put 100 static methods with the same signature into the same namespace without further differenciation? You can't do this... you'll get an compile error even for two with the same signature in the same namespace / class. If you put them into different classes you still need to call the method via concrete instance or concreteclassname::staticmethodname. And you should know at this point what you want to call/achieve. I think, you are comparing  apples and oranges. The second statement has nothing to do with syntax and more with software architecture.

Comment: @Beachwalker It's not same signature, Class Vehicles contains 212 class of Vehicle with different name.

Comment: @Mahdi as I said... and if you put your method into every class then you need to call it with knowing the instance or classname -> you would see only the fitting method not the ones of other derrived classes! if you put these methods into the namespace THEY HAVE THE SAME SIGNATURE. Try to move this to chat if you don't understand what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace cls {
    void met() {
    }
}
```

Welcome to C++, enjoy your stay.

Comment: Awesome, however now I can't have variables as same name with namespace... `class cls z;` throws an error

Comment: Your code also don't let me to define properties in namespace scope

Comment: give the namespace another name and stay with cls as class name - you'd have to qualify the function with the namespace's name: `cls z; cls_namespace::met();` It's not the same as in C#. But it *is* not C#, it's C++/CLI after all. So you can't have everything the same in both languages - then one of them would be superfluos.